# How to add a key map in Emacs source code?

Tags: keymap, c, source

I found ESC-prefix and Control-X-prefix defined in keymap.c:

```
initial_define_key (global_map, 033, "ESC-prefix");
initial_define_key (global_map, Ctl ('X'), "Control-X-prefix");
```

But no matter what I try I can't add a map for Super (Hyper) key.
And this isn't working

```
Lisp_Object s_map;
...
s_map = Fmake_keymap (Qnil);
Fset (intern_c_string ("s-map"), s_map);
Ffset (intern_c_string ("S-prefix"), s_map);
...
initial_define_key (global_map, 0xffeb, "S-prefix");  // tried many codes
...
initial_define_key (s_map, 'z', "my-function");
```

Nothing:

```
s-z is undefined
```

I also have a question what `#define Ctl(c) ((c)&037)` does? Because 037 is no a key code of any Control (left or right).

Can you provide a working example of adding a key map to the source code?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a keymap and a keymap variable to *the Emacs C source code*? Or do you just want to define a keymap and a keymap variable (e.g., in your own Lisp code)?

Comment: I want to understand how this is done in source code. Can't sleep well if I don't understand something). I just hack sources now and have questions.

Comment: It may depend on the OS, e.g., it would likely be different for an OSX build `--with-ns`:  **Qsuper** /  `ns_command_modifier` / `ns-command-modifier` in `nsterm.m` and `ns-win.el`.  You might also try grepping for **Qsuper** and **super_modifier** in `xterm.c` and `w32fns.c` and `globals.h`  I hope you are able to get *some* sleep eventually -- obsessions and sleep seldom mix.

Comment: By the way, `super` and `hyper` are two different keys. Not sure if you know it.

Comment: @MatthewRock yes I know

Comment: Since Super and Hyper are modifiers, maybe emacs doesn't handle them like other keypresses. Did you try adding a keymap for e.g. `s-z` itself ?

Comment: But Meta and Control are also modifiers. I wanted to do the same thing. Now I just use `(global-set-key (kbd "s-z") ...` in bindings.el

Comment: re `(c)&037`: it refers to [ASCII control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart), not the CTRL keyboard key.